# Swagger jaxrs provide class description for POST request

Tags: jax-rs, swagger

With Swagger I can annotate the response object with

```
 @ApiOperation(value = "save a user", response = User.class)
 @POST
 public Response saveUser(String message){...}
```

which then generates the json response structure as for example

```
User {
     id (integer, optional),
     email (string, optional)  
 }
```

How can I specify the structure of the POST message without changing the method parameter type of the saveUser method?

I am looking for something like:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "save a user", response = User.class, request = User.class)
```

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way to do that.  You should check out the documentation for [annotating your models](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-JAXRS-Quickstart#annotate-your-models).  In your example, I would annotate your model as:

```
@ApiModel(value = "An individual model details")
User {

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "description", required=true)
  id,
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "description", required=true)
  email  
}
```

Then your resource would look like:

```
@POST
@ApiOperation(value = "short description", notes = "long description", response = User.class)
Response create(@ApiParam(value = "description", required = true) String message) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Note the ApiParam annotation on the incoming message, while the ApiOperation annotation describes the outgoing model.